# Graph with three bridges not in single path whith perfect matching

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, matching-theory

I want to show that it is possible to have a cubic graph $G$ with the following two properties:

1. $G$ has three bridges that do not lie on a single path.
2. $G$ has a perfect matching.

My attempts have been modifying the following graph

[image: graph]

(Image source: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98385/cubic-graphs-without-a-perfect-matching-and-a-vertex-incident-to-three-bridges)

I have tried to replace the vertex $1$ with a graph such that it allowed to include all the edges adjacent to $1$ but all of my attempts have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Can't you just replace $1$ with a triangle ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]
Please forgive the MS paint. This graph is clearly cubic and has a perfect matching. Notice also that there is no path that can cross all three bridges at once.

Comment: Baffled why the OP dismissed my previous comment ? ... It does have a perfect matching. ... Great picture !

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I thought the matching couldn't include the bridges, sorry about it.

Comment: @AldoSayeg ... That's cool Dude $ \ddot \smile$